# What is a reliable way to detect which line break characters are used in a file?

Tags: windows, unix, text, encoding

I'm reading text files but I don't know in advance the kind of line ending used in this file. I need to know whether it uses UNIX `\n` or windows style `\r\n` line endings.

What is a reliable and fast way to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing a trick, but couldn't you just open the file as binary and read bytes until you see `'\n'`? If you saw `'\r'` just before, it's Windows. Otherwise it's Unix.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia:

> The file command also detects the type
>   of EOL used:

```
file myfile.txt
> > myfile.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems

Of course, [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) would only work on Unix systems. I'm sure someone else will answer one for Windows.

Comment: Basically, what I am interested in is, is the way the file command does it. I cannot run a shell command in my use case.

Comment: @Fabian: I'm curious now. What's your use case? It wouldn't be to break down different lines. Does this have to do with encoding or file types?

Comment: I have a textarea in a web browser and I need to split pasted text into separate lines. Further I want to be able to reassemble the text with the original line breaks.